# PHP/Java Bridge java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, php-java-bridge

I have setup PHP/Java Bridge with working examples in netbeans tomcat directory.
What doesnt work is using custom JAR 
Here is my code:

```
package com.micha;

public class Hello1Bean {
    public Hello1Bean()
    {}
    String hi() {return "This is my hello message";}
    String hello(String name) {return "Hello" + name;}
}
```

And the php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        require_once ("java/Java.inc");
        $world = new Java("com.micha.Hello1Bean");
        echo java_values($world->hi());
        echo "Hello Working Thingy\n\n";

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I check `http://localhost:8084/JavaBridge/mytest.php`:

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught [[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: Invoke failed: [[o:Hello1Bean]]->hi. Cause: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: hi(). Candidates: [] VM: 1.6.0_25@http://java.sun.com/" at:
#-6 php.java.bridge.JavaBridge.checkM(JavaBridge.java:1085)
#-5 php.java.bridge.JavaBridge.Invoke(JavaBridge.java:1024)
#-4 php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequest(Request.java:417)
#-3 php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequests(Request.java:500)
#-2 php.java.bridge.http.ContextRunner.run(ContextRunner.java:145)
#-1 php.java.bridge.ThreadPool$Delegate.run(ThreadPool.java:60)
#0 C:\Users\Micha\.netbeans\7.1.2\apache-tomcat-7.0.22.0_base\webapps\JavaBridge\java\Java.inc(232): java_ThrowExceptionProxyFactory->getProxy(2, 'com.micha.Hello...', 'T', true)
#1 C:\Users\Micha\.netbeans\7.1.2\apache-tomcat-7.0.22.0_base\webapps\JavaBridge\java\Java.inc(360): java_Arg->getResult(true)
#2 C:\Users\Micha\.netbeans\7.1.2\apache-tomcat-7.0.22.0_base\webapps\JavaBridge\java\Java.inc(366): java_Client->getWrappedResult(true)
#3 C:\Users\Micha\.netbean in C:\Users\Micha\.netbeans\7.1.2\apache-tomcat-7.0.22.0_base\webapps\JavaBridge\java\Java.inc on line 195

    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.handle(FastCGIServlet.java:499)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.doGet(FastCGIServlet.java:521)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    php.java.servlet.PhpCGIFilter.doFilter(PhpCGIFilter.java:126)
```

Before I had a ClassNotFoundException so it knows there is a a class but for some odd reason I cant call the function. ( if I replace "`com.micha.Hello1Bean`" with some class 
that doesnt exist then I get that exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is not public, try:

```
public String hi() {
       return "This is my hello message";
}
```

Comment: I figured this out earlier but I have had connection problems so I couldnt post, anyway you get the green check :)